# JSP chatting with ajax 

Tags: ajax, jsp, chat

I am writing one web chat program using AJAX (a little bit). It is working when both users open a chat page, but I want to open a window when one user send data to others.

Comment: I've done a simple project with respect to JSP Chat [JSP Practice: Simple chat](http://ben-bai.blogspot.tw/2012/01/jsp-practice-simple-chat.html)

Answer (score 1):

Unless both users have a common web page (that you control) open, then this wouldn't be possible.  However for the sake of providing a solution, let's agree on some assumptions:

1. Both of the visitors are on your home page
2. One of the visitors opens a chat window and enters a message.

Once that message is entered, you use AJAX to send the message to the server.  At this point it would probably be best to go ahead and save the message into a database (just my two cents worth on that part). The home page would have to be set up to poll for any messages every so often also using AJAX (I'd suggest every 30 seconds or so, depending on the purpose of this application).  If a new message is received, then it would respond by opening a chat window (`window.open(url)`) and the discussion can commence.

Answer (score 1):

Both user should have your webpage as open. This is the basic requirement. 
After that when both user are active on page you can use AJAX to feed a servlet that takes in the username and pops data that tells the page if there is new message unread for that particular user. If there is new message than it should open a window automatically through Javascript and takes it to the main chat page. This is done in many live chat applications where user moving on site suddenly gets a pop and a window opens to chat.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to write some javascript to open a new window when a message is received.  How are you sending the message - [reverse Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Ajax)?

Presumably both users will need to have your chat applications web page open so that you have somewhere to put the reverse ajax hook code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use some JS code to open a new window?

```
winRef = window.open( URL, name [ , features [, replace ] ] )
```